# Combo Box no Devuelve las Datos del Select con AJAX

Tags: ajax

he realizado un combo box que debe devolver los numeros de cuenta bancaria de un banco, porque un banco puede tener mas de un numero  cuenta registrado, estoy enviando una consulta mediante AJAX a la base de datos he insertando un HTML en el option que muestra los numero de cuenta de acuerdo a la selección del banco del Usuario, adjunto les coloco el codigo html, el AJAX y la consulta. Por favor Agradezco su Ayuda.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready (function () {
  $("#cbx_banco").change(function(){
    $("#cbx_banco option:selected").each(function(){
      var idbanco = fk_id_banco = $(this).val();

      alert (idbanco);

      var banco = fk_id_banco;

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"getbankacounts.php",
        data: banco,
        success: function(data)
          $("#cbx_counts").html(data);
        })
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Este es el codigo de el destino del AJAX donde hago el query

```
<?php


require('conexion.php');


$fk_id_banco = $_POST['fk_id_banco'];

$queryCb = "select nr_Cuenta_bancaria from cuenta_bancaria where fk_id_Banco 
= '$fk_id_banco' ";

$resultadoCb = $mysqli->query($queryCb);

$html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Cuenta </option>";


while ($opcionesCta = $resultadoCb->fecth_assoc()){


$html = "<option value = 


'".$opcionesCta['nr_Cuenta_bancaria']."'>".
$opcionesCta['nr_Cuenta_bancaria']."</option>";

}

echo $html;
```

Y Este es el Fragmento del HTML donde se debe mostrar los numero de cuenta de acuerdo a lo que el usuario selecione como banco.

```
<select id="cbx_counts" class="custom-select" name="cbx_counts" >

<option value="">Nro Cuenta: </option>
<option value=""><?php $opciones['nr_Cuenta_bancaria'] ?></option>

</select>
```

Comment: Revisa la identación del código (agregando espacios). Trata de ponerla en todos los ejemplos. Eso nos ayuda a ayudarte y clarifica la pregunta. Me tomé la libertad de editar la parte superior y pareciera que la función succes no tiene su `{` inicial. Pero podría ser otra cosa.

Comment: Hola Emilio Gracias por tu comentario, me indicas que debo colocar {  en que parte antes de colocar la function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimados Tenía Varios Errores aquí coloco el codigo que si me funciona Perfecto. Agradezco las Sugerencias que me puedan dar al respecto ahora debo envia una consulta con los datos seleccionados.

Script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready (function () {
                    $("#cbx_banco").change(function(){
                        $("#cbx_banco option:selected").each(function(){
                            var idbanco = fk_id_banco = $(this).val();

                                  var banco = fk_id_banco;

                              $.ajax({
                                type: 'post',
                                url: 'obtenercuenta.php',
                                data: {idbanco:idbanco},
                                success: function(datos)
                                {
                                  $("#cbx_counts").html(datos);
                                }
                            })
                        });
                    });
                 });


    </script>
```

Aqui PHP de la Consulta

```
<?php


$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','gerardo','1234','bghdhdhdhnjjj');


 $fk_id_banco = $_POST["idbanco"];


$sql = "select nr_Cuenta_bancaria from cuenta_bancaria where fk_id_Banco 
 ='$fk_id_banco'";


$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);



 $html = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar Cuenta </option>";



 while ($opciones = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta)):; ?>

  <option id="fk_id_banco" selected="selected" <?php echo 
     $opciones['nr_Cuenta_bancaria']; ?>"><?php echo $opciones['nr_Cuenta_bancaria']; 
     ?></option>


    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Aqui el HTML donde Se Muestra

```
   <select id="cbx_counts" class="custom-select"  name="cbx_counts" >

   <option value="">Nro Cuenta: </option>

   <option value=""><?php $opciones['nr_Cuenta_bancaria'] ?></option>

   </select>
```